# imagecreatefrompng error

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
function LoadPNG($imgname)
{
    /* Attempt to open */
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);

    /* See if it failed */
    if(!$im)
    {
        /* Create a blank image */
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        /* Output an error message */
        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
    }

    return $im;
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$img = LoadPNG('http://www.prideofhome.com/wp-content/uploads/328145505image_11.png');

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

i am getting error..how to solve.is imagecreatefrompng doesnt support the file from remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a file from a remote server, use `imagecreatefromstring` in conjunction with `file_get_contents`:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imgname));
```

Note that a URL can be used as a filename with `file_get_contents` only if fopen wrappers have been enabled.

If this doesn't solve your problem, clarify your question. Give at least the error you're receiving. :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `@` will let you see what's wrong. Either the [apppropriate option](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) isn't set, or the gd extension was built without PNG support, or the remote file doesn't exist/can't be downloaded.