# I can't open this PNG file with imagecreatefrompng()

Tags: php, load, png, gd

Here is a PNG file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHOgE.png *(Yes, never mind that it's a funny penguin with a sign...)*

When running the following code:

```
imagecreatefrompng('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHOgE.png');
```

I get an error:

> **PHP Warning**:  imagecreatefrompng() *[function.imagecreatefrompng]*: Cannot read image data in /home/test/...

The PNG file seems to be fine - I can open it with different editors, and the Unix `file` command reports that it is:

> `PNG image, 640 x 360, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced`

**PHP version:** 5.2.13
**GD version:** bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Comment: does it work if the file is on your filesystem?

Comment: @Hamish: Wow! It opens fine locally. That's just weird.

Comment: @Hamish: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I did however find something that works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [imagecreatefrompng error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779725/imagecreatefrompng-error)

Comment: @dra: Oh, right. Although it wasn't obvious until now what the problem was.

Comment: True. I just thought I would help with the whole tagging of duplicates ;)

Comment: (General note) While the questions might have the same solution, it's impossible to tell if the other question is a duplicate given that the OP never mentioned what the error message was in the other case.

Comment: Could it be because there is no image at that URL? It returns a 301 header redirecting to http://i.imgur.com/NUl4v.png. Perhaps the redirect isn't being followed. Try using the actual URL of the image.

Comment: @DanGrossman I think that must be it. The only time the "Cannot read image data" error is generated is when the buffer size is 0, and if the redirect wasn't followed, the returned body would be empty.

Comment: You can reliably reproduce this problem with this image, right? I've gotten myself really curious about where the problem is, but I don't see how this could happen in the source code unless you also run into issues with file_get_contents. There *is* a slight difference in how the two methods request the resource, but not one that should have any impact here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have no idea why, but the following works:

```
imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://imgur.com/NUl4v.png'));
```

Comment: Ah, there is his problem: `imagecreatefrompng('http://imgur.com/NUl4v.png');` he was sending the URL to be parsed as an image. (rather than the contents of the URL)

Comment: @Earlz: No, that function expects a string.

Comment: @George, yes, that's what I'm saying: You are passing 'http://imgur...' to it instead of what the actual contents of that URL is(as in, you are passing the URL itself rather than the PNG data contained at the URL)

Comment: @Earlz - imagecreatefrompng expects filename, or path to the PNG image, and the documentation says "a URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.".

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to access it via a URL, see the [allow_url_fopen](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) configuration option. If this isn't enabled then PHP won't be able to load it from a remote resource.

Comment: I checked: this option is set to `on`.