# Can I use a URL as the source for imagecreatefromjpeg() without enabling fopen wrappers?

Tags: php, url, image-resizing, imagecreatefrompng

I know it’s possible to use imagecreatefromjpeg(), imagecreatefrompng(), etc. with a URL as the ‘filename’ with fopen(), but I'm unable to enable the wrappers due to security issues. Is there a way to pass a URL to imagecreatefromX() without enabling them?

I’ve also tried using cURL, and that too is giving me problems:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.../image31.jpg"); //Actually complete URL to image
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
var_dump($image);

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: So i don't know the URL you are using but i just tested this myself, and seemed to work.  I've used this method with ImageMagick in some projects, and in our case for security reasons, we needed to use a proxy server, so perhaps that could be your issue?

Comment: The var_dump says: resource(65) of type (gd)

Comment: Try dumping the `$data` to see what you are actually getting back.

Comment: string(215063) "����ExifMM*�����(1�2҇i�  ��' ��'Adobe Photoshop CS5 Macintosh2012:08:28 21:47:46�0221�����nv(~�HH����Adobe_CM��Adobed����       ��>�"�� ��?    3!1AQa"q�2���B#$R�b34r��C%�S���cs5���&D�TdE and it continues doing that for hundreds of lines.

Comment: *It continues the random characters for hundreds of lines*. Not including the string(215063) or Macintosh....

Comment: iRector, sounds like it was working, yes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can download the file using cURL then pipe the result into `imagecreatefromstring`.

Example:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imageurl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // good edit, thanks!
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); // also, this seems wise considering output is image.
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

Comment: +1, this is better than my suggestion of using a temporary file.  I tried to look for something like `imagecreatefromstring` but missed it among all the other `imagecreatefrom*` functions.

Comment: Alain thanks for the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, i had forgotten that one.  I also added CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER... seemed to make sense.

Comment: I know thats gotta be my answer, but I'm having an issue with displaying the image. See above for code.

Comment: for those who use binary transfer, we now should avoid using it because it is deprecated. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55635

Comment: we may also use this reply here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175664/3270433

Answer (score 1):

You could even implement a cURL based stream wrapper for 'http' using [stream_wrapper_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could always download the image (e.g. with cURL) to a temporary file, and then load the image from that file.