# imagecreatefromjpeg() and curl() timeout with http file

Tags: php, image, curl, server

I am running PHP's built in server with `php -S localhost:7777`. I am trying to do some stuff with images and I need to access the files through an absolute path like:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost:7777/img/rainbow.jpg');
```

But the server just times out when I try this, even though `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini and I also tried making sure it was on with `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true)`. I also tried the solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337639/can-i-use-a-url-as-the-source-for-imagecreatefromjpeg-without-enabling-fopen-w), using curl and it still times out just the same. However it does work to use a relative path, like:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('../img/rainbow.jpg');
```

Why should this be? I need it to be an absolute path because I need to route requests for images through an image resizer script, SLIR, which requires URLs in the form `/SLIR/w500-h300/path/to/image.jpg`, but the routing doesn't work through things like `imagecreatefromjpeg()` I believe because that isn't an HTTP request, but maybe I am mistaken about that?

Comment: Try `imagecreatefromjpeg('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/img/rainbow.jpg');`

Comment: That doesn't work. It just interprets that as localhost without the port number.

Comment: Hmm, it works on a remote server, so it must be some firewall issue.