# imagecreatefrompng: info being sent but not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so I haven't coded in a while so I've been piecing together codes. Anyway, I'm making a site where it will send the Post data from the index.php to the boutique.php. the boutique.php page has the imagecreatefrompng on it

When you send the form data from index.php it will select from the mysql database the option you selected on the index, send that, get the link from the database and send the link to the boutique.php.

Now I've gotten it work, when I include the page without putting in the  tag it and i echo the the image link tag from the boutique.php page, the link url shows up, so the code itself is being sent properly. BUT it also shows up the gibberish code:

ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC

and even when I put the page in the  the code is broken, but the image link is being sent.

Boutique.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
ob_start();
$image_data = ob_get_clean();
session_start();

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('data') or die('Could not select database');

$GetTanTable = "SELECT * FROM Pants  WHERE maincolor='Tan'";

$GetTan = mysql_query($GetTanTable) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

while ($RowTan = mysql_fetch_array($GetTan, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{

$GetPantsImage = $RowTan['image'];

if(isset($_POST['PTsubmit']) && $RowTan['subcolor'] == $_POST['PTan'])
{
$horizontal = 'right';
$vertical = 'bottom';

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($GetPantsImage);
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
$src = $_GET["src"];
}
}
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 500);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($image, $black);
imagealphablending($image, true); 
imagesavealpha($image, true);  
$horizontal = 'right';
$vertical = 'bottom';
switch ($horizontal) {
default:
$dest_x = $size[0] - 50;
}
switch ($vertical) {
default:
$dest_y = $size[1] - 50;
}

imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width,$watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
?>
```

Now even though the code is being sent properly, when I delete all the if, while statements and put a regular http:// code in the $GetPantsImage, it works. So I really don't understand

**THE CODE WORKS WHEN:** I take the if/while statements out and i put the actual url that is in the datase

Comment: You're outputting your image with [`imagejpeg()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) when you're declaring `header('Content-Type: image/png');` at the top of your file. 

You're probably looking for [`imagepng()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php).

Comment: I was hoping this would fix it but now it's just giving the code in gibberish for a PNG

Comment: what is the value of `$GetPantsImage` after setting it with your `$RowTan['image']` variable?

Comment: When i echo it on boutique.php, it's the image url (which is exactly what it's supposed to be) but for some reason it's like the imagecreatefrompng isn't taking it.

Comment: However I just put in the database the url with quotes. and an error came back Warning: imagecreatefrompng('http://sugarbabiesblog.com/images/thumbs/maykhakipants.png') so it's getting the url but not displaying the image

Comment: Warning: imagecreatefrompng('http://sugarbabiesblog.com/images/thumbs/maykhakipants.png') [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Answer (score 0):

Is the file you are trying to process on a remote server or local?

If it's remote then you must specify the full url:

http://sugarbabiesblog.com/images/thumbs/maykhakipants.png

(In your example you omit the http)

If it's local, you want to omit the domain name:

/images/thumbs/maykhakipants.png

Some insights here: [I can't open this PNG file with imagecreatefrompng()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175473/i-cant-open-this-png-file-with-imagecreatefrompng)

Comment: When i removed the http:// from the database link i got Warning: imagecreatefrompng(upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/zacmaur/public_html/nash/boutique.php on line 21