# PHP GD Image Showing Localhost But Not On Server

Tags: php, image, gd

I've always worked localhost on MAMP (PHP Version 5.4.10). I uploaded the EXACT same file onto a  server I purchased running LAMP (PHP Version 5.4.15-1~lucid+1). I opened the file localhost and the image loaded fine and correct. I uploaded the exact files onto the server and I get the broken image image. My code:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once('query.class.php');
$Server = new MinecraftServerStatus($IP = '69.65.42.155', $Port = 30465, $Timeout = 1);

 header('content-type: image/png');

$image = imagecreatefrompng('http://192.34.58.24/cfgd/images/o_image1.png');

$dark_grey = imagecolorallocate($image, 102, 102, 102);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 255, 0);

$font_path = 'Brixton';

$title = 'Knightsrp';
if($Port != 25565){
    $dip = $IP.':'.$Port;
}
else{
    $dip = $IP;
}

if($Server->Get('online')){
    $status = 'Online';
    $players = $Server->Get('numplayers').' / '.$Server->Get('maxplayers');
}
else{
    $status = 'Offline';
}

imagettftext($image, 30, 0, 10, 35, $white, $font_path, $title);
if($status == 'Online'){imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 5, 87, $green, $font_path, $status);}else{imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 5, 87, $red, $font_path, $status);}
if($status == 'Online'){imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 550, 87, $white, $font_path, $players);}
imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 350, 20, $white, $font_path, $dip);

imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

You can find the php class I use here: https://github.com/NoxNebula/Minecraft-Server-Status

Comment: Is GD installed on your remote server?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, yes GD is installed on both my server and localhost.

Comment: Is `$font_path` correct? Does the font exist on the server?

Comment: In your phpinfo, is `udp` registered as `stream socket transport protocol`?

Comment: errr, not sure what you mean. You can check phpInfo() here. http://192.34.58.24/cfgd/test.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779725/imagecreatefrompng-error

Will this work for you? Otherwise you may need to enable fopen for URLs on the server. See http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=95651 for a description of the needed changes to php.ini

Comment: I'm not getting an error its just a broken-image image. When running this exact same script on my local machine it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "broken image"?

Comment: This: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Ze5Xm5fW-4o/TUnUBt6ADUI/AAAAAAAABJA/2WGSLTNK1K4/s1600/broken-link-image-gif.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
```

Before

```
imagettftext($image, 30, 0, 10, 35, $white, $font_path, $title);
```